# Creating an anime (videos) streaming site - copyright problems?

Tags: copyright, video, streaming

My plan is to create a website that streams Dragon Ball, Dragon Ball Z and Dragon Ball Super episodes and offer a better service than competitors. I understand that hosting the videos itself is illegal, but when linked through other video sources that are out of my personal control, it is considered possible?

My question being, in general, will I get in personal trouble when I create such a website? I won't host or upload any videos myself. And will my website be viable from copyright infringements? I don't mind pushing the legal boundaries a bit, but I will not do it once I'm headed for a certain fine/personal problems due to copyright claims.

Comment: This is clearly a copyright violation. It doesn't matter if you don't have control over the content. You're still knowingly streaming it against the author's will.

Comment: On that way you'll become a distributor. And distributor on any illegal things is against law.

Comment: In the copyright law, the copyright holder has full right to how, where, when, and by whom their work is presented. You will need a license for this.

Answer (score 1):

That's in violation of copyright laws.  You have to be authorized by the owners of the videos to stream them. The only way to do this legally is to ask the company owning these series if you can stream them and become some sort of distributor.  This will not be free.

Comment: "likely constitutes piracy as well"  -- piracy is just a derogatory term for copyright infringement.